# How To Get Absolute Time Differences Between API Calls With Millisecond Precision?

Tags: python, multithreading, api, python-3.x

I have threaded API calls that need to coordinate API call times.

The nature of the application means I need to run razor thin margins up against the max API hit rate.

Currently I'm coordinating the time the API call is made from the local machine to the remote API using a shared object that stores the last API call time.

To account for connection speed differentials between the local machine & remote API I'm using a fall back response test, re-cueing the API call if 2 calls hit the API too soon, leading to a response error. (I really don't like this solution though... if you have a better one, please chime in.)

The problem:

time.time() doesn't give me enough precision on all platforms.  I need millisecond precision.

time.clock() as far as I understand deals with process time, not absolute time.  Therefore if the CPU is under different loads, it's going to vector off from absolute time based on those load differences.  Is this correct?

So with that in mind, what would be the best way to get the time differentials between API calls with millisecond precision?

Comment: As near as I can tell, not all the API calls return a timestamp.  Is there a param I have to set in Requests to get that time stamp on every call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The precision will still depend upon the platform, but you should use `timeit.default_timer`.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.default_timer):

> Define a default timer, in a platform-specific manner. On Windows, time.clock() has microsecond granularity, but time.time()‘s granularity is 1/60th of a second. On Unix, time.clock() has 1/100th of a second granularity, and time.time() is much more precise. On either platform, default_timer() measures wall clock time, not the CPU time. This means that other processes running on the same computer may interfere with the timing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  If you disable the network connection upon which the API relies of course `timeit` will provide incorrect timings, but so would anything...